# In a bash script, use /dev/stdin for first of multiple command line inputs in wrapped script

Tags: bash, stdin

Let's say I'm writing a bash script myscript.bash, which expects a single argument ($1).  One of things it does is call wrapped.py, a python script, which prompts the user for four inputs.  I want to submit $1 for the first of these inputs automatically, and then have the user prompted for the rest as normal.

How can I do this?  I tried `echo $1 | wrapped.py < /dev/stdin`, but this submits EOF for the second input requested by wrapped.py, causing a Python EOFError.  It does work if I echo -e "$1\na\nb\nc", that is, echo all four inputs...but I want the user to be prompted for the other three.  I could write a full-fledged wrapper for the Python script, but that creates maintenance issues, as an update to wrapped.py could e.g. add a fifth question.

Here's what the actual error looks like:

```
$ echo 'test_app' | django-startproject.py test_app tmp < /dev/stdin
Project name [PROJECT]: Project author [Lincoln Loop]: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-startproject.py", line 7, in <module>
    execfile(__file__)
  File "/home/rich/src/ll-django-startproject/bin/django-startproject.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/rich/src/ll-django-startproject/bin/django-startproject.py", line 5, in main
    start_project()
  File "/home/rich/src/ll-django-startproject/django_startproject/management.py", line 44, in start_project
    value = raw_input(prompt) or default
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way:

```
(echo "$1"; cat) | rest of the pipe here
```

The disadvantage of this aproach is that the rest of the pipe sees the input as a pipe, and tends to lose most of the nice "interactive" properties.  Then again, it depends on your script.

For anything more fancy, you should look into [`expect`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

Comment: Thanks.  That appears to work, except that I don't see the raw_input prompts for inputs 2-4 until I enter values for them, at which point they all print out at once.  Is there a workaround for that simpler than using `expect`?

Comment: Not that I know of.  That's a "no", for my personal situation in the world, because if I had to look for/build it, it wouldn't be the simplest anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up things like this:

Your bash script

```
#!/bin/sh

./test.py $1
```

And python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print("In py script now")
for i in sys.argv:
print i

print raw_input('What day is it? ')
print raw_input('What date is it? ')
print raw_input('What month is it? ')

print ("Exiting py script")
```

And run like this

```
./myscript.bash abc
```

Output

```
In py script now
./test.py
abc
What day is it? 65
65
What date is it? 98
98
What month is it? 14
14
Exiting py script
```

Comment: Thanks, but unless I'm missing something, you're not sending $1 to the first raw_input() call, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: $1 is available to your .py script. You can use it to assign to any variable there you want.